# git-svn died of signal 11

Tags: git, svn, migration, git-svn

When using git-svn to checkout a large repository, the following error occurs.

> error: git-svn died of signal 11

Most of the solutions on the internet didn't work for me.
But repositories larger than this are work.

My .git/config

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0 
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
    packedGitLimit = 256m
    packedGitWindowSize = 256m
    longpaths = true
[svn-remote "svn"]
    noMetadata = 1 
    url = svn://my_repository_url
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/svn/trunk
    branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/svn/*
    tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/svn/tags/*
[http]
    postBuffer = 524288000
[pack]
    deltaCacheSize = 512m
    packSizeLimit = 512m
    windowMemory = 2048m
```

Versions

perl: `v5.22.1`
git: `2.7.4`
svn: `1.9.3`
host: `Linux Mint 18.3 64x`

What more should I add?
Thanks.

Comment: Signal 11 is SEGFAULT which might indicate a bug in the program. Try upgrade/downgrade to different versions.

Comment: I saw this error immediately before git-svn died with signal 11: `Attempt to free unreferenced scalar: SV 0x7fffcf198880, Perl interpreter: 0x7fffcd5322a0 at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/SVN/Core.pm line 422.`